# mshtml fails with FAST_FAIL_INCORRECT_STACK after calling HideUI

Tags: c++, com, internet-explorer-11, mshtml

I have written an implementation of IDocHostUIHandler in order to provide an external object to JavaScript an embedded IE11 control.  One class provides implementations of IUnknown, IDispatch and IDocHostUIHandler.  The IDispatch interface is returned to GetExternal as the external object.
All calls to IDocHostUIHandler except GetExternal call into the original handler.

For example HideUI is implemented as:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler::HideUI(void)
{
    qDebug("Calling HideUI");
    if(m_defaultDocHostUIHandler)
    {
        HRESULT hr = m_defaultDocHostUIHandler->HideUI();
        qDebug("Called HideUI");
        return hr;
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

The same pattern is used for all of the other methods except GetExternal which is:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler::GetExternal(IDispatch **ppDispatch)
{
    qDebug("Calling GetExternal");
    *ppDispatch = (IDispatch*)this;
    return S_OK;
}
```

In JavaScript I execute the following:

```
var r1 = window.external.Test1();
```

This results in the following debug output tail:

```
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  Calling GetHostInfo
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  Called GetHostInfo
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler Release (ref now = 2)
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler AddRef (ref now = 3)
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  Calling GetHostInfo
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  Called GetHostInfo
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler Release (ref now = 2)
'2016-10-10 11:09:19'    DEBUG  Calling GetExternal
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler - IDispatch requested
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler AddRef (ref now = 3)
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler Release (ref now = 2)
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  Calling ShowUI
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  Called ShowUI
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  Calling HideUI
'2016-10-10 11:09:21'    DEBUG  Called HideUI
```

The final return from HideUI causes an INT 29h error with ecx = FAST_FAIL_INCORRECT_STACK.  The expected stack is 0x18D9C4 and the actual stack is 0x18D9A4, a discrepancy of 0x20.

I am completely mystified.  The other calls to my interface work correctly and it doesn't make any difference if I just return E_NOTIMPL from my implementation of HideUI. What could possibly be unbalancing the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that I was using ICustomDoc on the browser document when mshtml was being hosted by the WebBrowser control.  This is apparently not a good idea! Instead you should use the existing site provided by the WebBrowser control.  I found an example of the correct way to implement IDocHostUI here https://github.com/FastSpring/FsprgEmbeddedStoreWinMFC and it was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the `GetExternal` function you are returning an interface pointer without incrementing the reference count which will lead to reference count mismatching later. A better implementation would be:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE mtQtWebBrowserDocHandler::GetExternal(IDispatch **ppDispatch)
{
    qDebug("Calling GetExternal");
    *ppDispatch = (IDispatch*)this;
    this->AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

or use `QueryInterface` in there. If this is ATL, `InternalQueryInterface`. I suspect this is the cause of your error as you have a reference to the object that has probably been destroyed due to more `Release` calls than `AddRef` calls.

Comment: I am not a COM expert but I am fairly sure this is not the case.  The reference is obtained by mshtml.dll calling GetExternal() and then owned by it so it will AddRef and then Release when it is done with the reference..

Comment: Yes, you are correct about not being a COM expert. Any time you get a pointer like that in COM, the callee should AddRef() the interface so that when the caller calls Release() everything will be balanced as it should be.

Comment: Microsoft don't appear to agree with you.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691379(v=vs.85).aspx about AddRef. The rule in COM is if you hand over a copy of an interface, you call AddRef and the recipient is responsible for calling Release().

Comment: Thanks, the Microsoft code seems to have been used, as shown, in a number of projects which I assume work, but more by luck than judgement it would seem.